# how Irvine32.lib makes a few unsupported functions available in VC

Tags: winapi, masm, irvine32

With `Irvine32.lib` linked, and `irvine32.inc` included, I can invoke a few functions that VC originally does not support, such as **Clrscr()** or **Gotoxy()**.

VC has never supported those functions.

So if I invoke **Clrscr()** somewhat, then the actual binary data for **Clsscr()** must be fired from some OS supported dlls such as `ntdll.dll` or `kernel32.dll`, both of which, however, clearly do not have it supported.

I *Dumpbin-ed* Irvine32.lib but I could not find the location from which that function is called.

How does `Irvine32.lib` magically make it available to call the unsupported functions I mentioned?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would Irvine's library be limited to the functions available in Microsoft's C runtime library (I assume that's what you mean by "VC")? As a separate library it can implement any function it wants.

Comment: That is correct. But at which module is the actual function implemented? Does Irvine32.lib contain the Clrscr()'s implementation?

Comment: So the better question should be where is Clrscr()...?

Comment: Probably. Write a small program that uses the `Clrscr` function, set a breakpoint at the call and then step into the function.

Comment: Oh.. yeah definitely. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for Irvine is available!  If you looked at it you would see that Kip, used the following Win32 API calls to implement his versions:

**Clrscr**
`GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo`
`WriteConsoleOutputCharacter`
`WriteConsoleOutputAttribute`
`SetConsoleCursorPosition`

**Gotoxy**
`SetConsoleCursorPosition`

If you don't like his ways, you could always implement your own versions.

Comment: Thanks. I eventually had to download the original code for Irvine32.lib and see how it turns into a binary obj file containing functions properly implemented for the end users.